# pam_exec and security

Tags: pam

I would really like to use the PAM module `pam_exec` to do some account setup and teardown activities during a session.  I have written a simple test script that runs and logs some runtime data so that i can see what is happening.

It seems to me that the exec'd script has to be executable by the effective UID of whoever is running the command that triggers PAM.  This makes sense.  However, I want a bit more security  in this process.  For example, it seems to me that if I have a script that pokes a record into a database on account login/logout then that script has to be executable by ALL users all the time.

I would much prefer to have the script be visible and executable ONLY by root or some other special-purpose account and have `pam_exec` `suid` the script for the unprivileged user.

Why?  In the case of the database script I would not want the user to login then execute the script by hand to seemingly "logout".

I've thought about trying to put the script in the "sudoers" file but that still enables anyone to run it whenever they like.

It seems like the only option is to hack pam_exec to allow a "run as" option.

It is late on a Friday afternoon and I may be missing something trivial.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to me that the exec'd script has to be executable by the
>   effective UID of whoever is running the command that triggers PAM.
>   This makes sense.

Sounds like you are running pam_exec under the "session" line.  If you run your pam_exec script from "auth" it will be run by the root users (UID 0), so it doesn't need to be executable by the user any longer.  This way the user will not be able to run the script manually to spoof a logout.

You could probably also run your script from the "account" line, I believe the only time that a pam module executes with user permissions is when it is executing pam_open_session() or pam_close_session().

Comment: Turns out that even in "session" mode root owns the plugin ... depending on where in the pam.d conf file(s) you put it.  If you have selinux installed then you might have to put the plugin above the selinux calls.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand the problem.  If you're tracking a user login session, that is set up by a process running as root (whether it be sshd or login or some other similar program).  The PAM stack generally all runs as root through opening the session.  I'm not entirely sure where in the session creation process the UID is permanently changed, but it's fairly late in the process, since writing to utmp, etc., all has to be done as root.

You therefore are unlikely to run into this problem with normal login sessions.  The main places where PAM is used by non-root users is for things like screensavers that run on behalf of the user, but that seems like exactly the case where you don't want the user to run your script.

If you're trying to run something as part of sudo or su, the problem may be that `pam_exec` by default runs the program as the real user ID.  In those cases, I think you may need to run the program as the effective user ID to accomplish what you want.  There is a `seteuid` PAM option to `pam_exec` that tells `pam_exec` to do that.